# Snowflake Create or Replace Table as value Not Recognized

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a view called `View_A`.

`View_A` looks like this:

```
View_A
col_1 varchar
```

I am trying to run this SQL statement:

```
create or replace table database_name.schema_name.table_b as 
    select * from database_name.schema_name.view_a;
```

I keep getting the following error message:

> Numeric value 'K' is not recognized.

Why would I get this error message, especially if the only column in `View_a` is a varchar data type?

Comment: Edited my post (more characters added to fit min length so I can submit comment)

Comment: For debugging, did you try `create or replace table database_name.schema_name.table_b as select col_1 from database_name.schema_name.view_a`
?

Comment: I didn't but I figured out what was wrong.

If you can figure out why someone was allowed to create view_a in the first place, I'll give you credit for solving the question though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.

In order to create `view_a`, someone added a filter

`col_1 IN (1,2,3)` and didn't put single quotes around the values between the parenthesis.

I'm not sure why it was allowed to create the view in the first place, but putting in the single quotes made it run fine.

```
col_1 IN ('1','2','3')
```

Comment: Most databases will allow you to put numbers into a varchar column for WHERE clauses and will implicitly convert those to strings when evaluated.  That is why the view was allowed to be created.